# How to properly install Tex Live on Ubuntu?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

When I search for installing Tex Live on Ubuntu, the recommended way is to use the `apt install texlive-...`, unfortunately this method does not allow any package install from `tlmgr`:

```
tlmgr update --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

It seems the only way is to install Tex Live manually and not rely on `apt`. However, there are not many tutorials.

Is it worth it?

Comment: Does this method help? : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/120578

Comment: you can update the version you have using apt,or install upstream texlive from tug, but that is a completly different installation not just enabling `tlmgr`

Comment: note this is no different to every other program you use on ubuntu. For most users, most of the time it is better to install via apt to get a consistent installation and managed dependencies with other linux packages.  But you can always get more up to date versions by installing applications from upstream development sites, if you are prepared to manage dependencies yourself.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The issue with apt is when a package is missing. The google search `ubuntu texlive <package name>` doesn't always help and it is sometime hard to know which texlive-*** package contains what I need. For instant `expkv-cs` is not available on 20.04.

Comment: Don't Google, use `apt-file search package.sty` and it will tell you which Ubuntu bundle it comes from (if provided). Much more reliable. If you need bleeding edge, never use larex from Linux dist, they are hardly ever updated from one incarnation to another.

Comment: use apt to list files, or one of the websites that list ubuntu packages you don't need google, also just install texlive-full so then you don't need to worry. I have the system texlive, one I compiled from source, and tug texlive 2020, 2021 and 2022, it's not that big by modern standards.